# Pagination custom post type not working with rewrite slug

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, pagination

I can't find the way of making my pagination to work on my post type (this is not on an archive-posttype.php). I've rewrited my post type, but the second page isn't working if I do the rewriting ("medias/actualites"), but it works if I have the non-rewrited slug ("actualite").

I do the rewrite because my client wants to have the "medias/actualites" in the url, but with that, the pagination return a 404 on the second page...

This is my post type

```
$args = array(
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-site-alt2',
    'label' => __('Actualités', 'domain'),
    'description' => __('Actualités', 'domain'),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'supports' => array('title', 'page-attributes', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'post-formats', 'excerpt',),
    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'medias/actualites',
        'with_front' => false,
    ),

);
```

Edit : and I'm using a plugin to translate /medias/actualites to /media/press-news

Comment: Are you referring to `medias/actualites/page/2` and pages 3, 4, etc.? If so, then you should enable archive for the post type, i.e. `'has_archive' => true`. But what does the page at `medias/actualites` currently show? And by "translate", did you mean you're redirecting `medias/actualites` to `media/press-news`?

Comment: Yes, I'm refering to those pages. I wanted to do this by archive-actualite, but my plugin (polylang (not pro)) doesn't accept the translation of the page title.  **medias/actualites** shows all of my actualite with a custom wp_query

Comment: Lol sorry about the "translate" thing.. So are the `medias/actualites` and `media/press-news` static Pages (i.e. posts of the `page` type)?

Comment: When `has_archive` is `false` (i.e. archive is *not* enabled), then `medias/actualites` will naturally result in a 404 error, but you said that it displays all the posts in your CPT, hence I asked if you've got a static page at that URL. But even so, the 404 error on pages 2, 3, etc. is normal since WordPress treats the URL (e.g. `medias/actualites/page/2`) as a single CPT request.

Comment: It display my posts because it's indeed a custom page (as I said, not archive-actualite.php). So how can I "fix" the 404 ?

Comment: Yes, I was well aware of the "not on an archive-posttype.php" in the question, but it doesn't necessarily mean you're indeed using a custom Page as the post type archive, so I asked. Nevertheless, I hope my answer helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on the comments, you confirmed that you're using a custom Page (i.e. post of the `page` type) as the post type's archive, which means you either have both the `media` and `actualites` Pages (where `actualites` is a child of the `media` Page) or that you used a parent Page for the CPT archive.

And normally, going to page 2, 3, etc. of a Page will not going to result in a 404 error; however, your post type's rewrite slug is `medias/actualites`, therefore `medias/actualites/page/2` (or `page/3`, `page/4`, etc.) will result in the 404 error because WordPress treats the URL as a single CPT request.

But fortunately, you can get rid of the 404 error by using a custom rewrite rule which can be added using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/):

```php
// First, register the CPT.
register_post_type( 'actualite', array( ... your args ... ) );

// Then add the rewrite rule.
// Note: With pagename, you must use the full page path, i.e. <parent slug>/<child slug>
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^medias/actualites/page/(\d+)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=medias/actualites&paged=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
/* Or if using a parent Page:
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^medias/actualites/page/(\d+)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=your-cpt-archive&paged=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
*/
```

PS: Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules and just use `get_query_var( 'paged' )` to get the page number.

And if you already have a custom rewrite rule, you can add it to the question and I'll help you fix it.

Comment: That's great, it's working on the french version ! But how can I do this with my english version ? I've tried to replace **medias/actualites** with **en/press-news/press** ...

Comment: Help a lot ! For the english version, did this to make it works : **add_rewrite_rule(
    '^en/press-news/news/page/(\d+)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=press-news/news&paged=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);**